# Comparing complexity of counting frequency of each integer in a list

Tags: java, python-3.x

To count the frequency of each Integer in a list the Java-8 code using streams is:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        List<Integer> lst = Arrays.asList(1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5);
        Map<Integer,Integer> map = lst.stream()
                .collect( Collectors.groupingBy( Function.identity(), Collectors.summingInt(e -> 1) ));
        for(Integer key: map.keySet())
            System.out.println(key+" : "+map.get(key));
    }
}
```

The above also includes the import statements though.
Now compare it with python code:

```
x=[1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5]  
for elem in x:  
     d[elem]=d.get(elem,0)+1
```

This is insane if one compares the complexity. Python is too concise. I am not sure if there is a simpler way to do it in java. It seems making a simple Map and looping over will be a much cleaner approach than using streams for this purpose. And probably the groupingBy functions are for more complex things.

Comment: You can basically write the exactly equivalent loop in Java (and I think it will have better performance anyway)

Answer (score 0):

A even simpler way is to just use a normal HashMap without any collectors.

You can relate this more with your Python code.

```java
public static void main(String args[]){
        List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5);
        Map<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (final int item : list) {
           map.put(item, map.getOrDefault(item, 0) + 1);
        }
        map.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " " + v));
    }
```